# Scp fails in one direction for admin but is successful with root user

Tags: scp

I am able to do a scp from server A to another server B using admin  but the same admin is not able to send files back from server B to server A. I used scp -vv and the detials look as below:

Can a admin not scp files in some cases? if so how do I check the previlidges?

```
Executing: program /usr/local/bin/ssh host 140.199.280.888, user adm, command scp -v -t /home/adm/test
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 140.199.280.888 [140.199.280.888 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pro/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pro/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pro/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '140.199.280.888' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/prov/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pro/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pro/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pro/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
adm@140.199.280.888's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/adm/test
Setting up release specific environment variables...
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/adm/test/
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 0
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
Setting up release specific environment variables...
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 6 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
adm@pro% debug2: channel 0: write failed
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.3 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

How could I resolve this. Or wht am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known issue .bashrc and scp (excacly output from bash and non interactive shell). I solved this problem by modifying the part of .bashrc to execute only for interactive shell

```
case $- in
*i*)    # interactive shell
alias cc='clearCache.sh'

echo 'Alias:
cc       - clear cache
;;
esac
```

Links to such problems:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/strange-scp-error-and-fail-664945/
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527
- https://serverfault.com/questions/485487/use-bashrc-without-breaking-sftp